# Generic GDI+ cursor capture time loop

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing, screen-capture, mouse-cursor

I want to capture both cursor and desktop with the following code. I used cursor capture and desktop capture functions as below. then I looped these functions with a timer and made continuous capture. After working for a while, I started getting an error as seen in the bottom picture. I'm waiting for support to fix the error.

```
static Bitmap CaptureDesktop()
        {
            SIZE size;
            IntPtr hBitmap;
            IntPtr hDC = Win32Stuff.GetDC(Win32Stuff.GetDesktopWindow());
            IntPtr hMemDC = GDIStuff.CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

            size.cx = Win32Stuff.GetSystemMetrics
                      (Win32Stuff.SM_CXSCREEN);

            size.cy = Win32Stuff.GetSystemMetrics
                      (Win32Stuff.SM_CYSCREEN);

            hBitmap = GDIStuff.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, size.cx, size.cy);

            if (hBitmap != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                IntPtr hOld = (IntPtr)GDIStuff.SelectObject
                                       (hMemDC, hBitmap);

                GDIStuff.BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, size.cx , size.cy, hDC,
                                               0, 0, GDIStuff.SRCCOPY);

                GDIStuff.SelectObject(hMemDC, hOld);
                GDIStuff.DeleteDC(hMemDC);
                Win32Stuff.ReleaseDC(Win32Stuff.GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);
                Bitmap bmp = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
                GDIStuff.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
                GC.Collect();
                return bmp;
                
            }
            return null;
      
        }


          static Bitmap CaptureCursor(ref int x, ref int y)
          {
              Bitmap bmp;
              IntPtr hicon;
              Win32Stuff.CURSORINFO ci = new Win32Stuff.CURSORINFO();
              Win32Stuff.ICONINFO icInfo;
              ci.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(ci);
              if (Win32Stuff.GetCursorInfo(out ci))
              {
                  if (ci.flags == Win32Stuff.CURSOR_SHOWING)
                  {
                      hicon = Win32Stuff.CopyIcon(ci.hCursor);
                      if (Win32Stuff.GetIconInfo(hicon, out icInfo))
                      {
                          x = ci.ptScreenPos.x - ((int)icInfo.xHotspot);
                          y = ci.ptScreenPos.y - ((int)icInfo.yHotspot);

                          Icon ic = Icon.FromHandle(hicon);
                          bmp = ic.ToBitmap();
                          bmp.Dispose();
                          return ic.ToBitmap(); ;
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                  }
              }

              return null;
          }

      

        public static Bitmap CaptureDesktopWithCursor()
        {
            int cursorX = 0;
            int cursorY = 0;
            Bitmap desktopBMP;
            Bitmap cursorBMP;
            Bitmap finalBMP;
            Graphics g;
            Rectangle r;

            desktopBMP = CaptureDesktop();
            cursorBMP = CaptureCursor(ref cursorX, ref cursorY);
            if (desktopBMP != null)
            {
                if (cursorBMP != null)
                { 
                    r = new Rectangle(cursorX, cursorY, cursorBMP.Width, cursorBMP.Height);
                    g = Graphics.FromImage(desktopBMP);
                    g.DrawImage(cursorBMP, r);
                    g.Flush();
                    g.Dispose();

                    return desktopBMP;
                }
                else
                    return desktopBMP;
            }

            return null;

        }
```

and put it in the timer loop.

```
private void Display(Bitmap desktop)
        {
            Graphics g;
            Rectangle r;
             if (desktop != null)
             {
                 r = new Rectangle(0,0,ssWithMouseViewer.Width, ssWithMouseViewer.Height);
                 g = ssWithMouseViewer.CreateGraphics();
               
                 g.DrawImage(desktop,r);
                 g.Flush();
                 g.Dispose();
                ssWithMouseViewer.Image?.Dispose();
            }
        }


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Display(CaptureScreen.CaptureDesktopWithCursor());
           
        }
```

After a certain time I get the following error. please your support.

[image]